# Android recording video and transmit to a PC via Socket

Tags: android, sockets, camera, surveillance

I want to transmit the video to PC while recording it on Android phone with camera, i.e, real time recording video and transmit it. At the same time, the PC or server can play the video. It somehow likes making Android phone camera as a surveillance camera while the PC as a screen. Anyone can give me some advice or guide?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In stackoverflow, you usually post the status of your work and ask how to solve a technical issue, not ask for a solution. Please refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any app that can record and stream at the same time, but here are two apps that can stream: IP Webcam and DroidCam. 
They won't yield a very high frame rate though, I'm getting about 10 fps on Galaxy S2, both tethered via USB cable and on WIFI